# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"default" | "red" | "green" | "blue"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, linaria

I am using React and TypeScript in my app. How do I get rid of below error?

```
import { styled } from "linaria/react";

type Color = {
  color: "default" | "red" | "green" | "blue";
};


const handleColorType = ({ color }: Color) => {
  switch (color) {
    case "default":
      return "#03a9f3";
    case "red":
      return "#f56342";
    case "green":
      return "#f56342";
    case "blue":
      return "#f56342";
    default:
      return "#fff";
  }
};

export const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 150px auto 0;
  color: ${({ color }) => handleColorType({ color // <---- here I get the error })};
`;
```

Then I get this Typescript error:

> (property) color: "default" | "red" | "green" | "blue" Type 'string |
> undefined' is not assignable to type '"default" | "red" | "green" |
> "blue"'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"default" |
> "red" | "green" | "blue"'.ts(2322) color.ts(2, 3): The expected type
> comes from property 'color' which is declared here on type 'Color'

Comment: A type definion like `type Color = "default" | "red" | "green" | "blue"` means it has only 4 valid values...Any other value apart from these 4 is not allowed.

Comment: The problem is not with the function, but at the call-site. Do you have any variable named "color" which you are then using to construct `{ color }` object at the call-site?

Comment: Like.. `handleColorType({ color // <---- here I get the error })`, what is the type of `color` here??

Comment: With a generic <Color> like `export const Title = styled.h1<Color>` it's working. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define type of prop as Color in styled component aswell

```
 color: ${({ color }: Color) => handleColorType({ color })};
```

because now its just optional string

Comment: not that's not working. Here I have to return a string as color

Comment: Sorry, try to declare props type of Styled component: `export const Title = styled.h1<Color>` according to [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)